# Ef Core SplitQuery performance/usage

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have some questions about the use cases for split queries.

Say I have something like this:

```
public class Product 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }      
    public string Name { get; set; } = CwdiConstants.NO_VALUE;
   
    public ICollection<Color>? Colors { get; } 
    public ICollection<Style>? Styles { get; } 

}//Cls
```

If I call:

```
var productsSingle= _db.Products
    .Include(p => p.Colors)
    .Include(p => p.Styles)
    .AsSingleQuery()
    .ToList();
```

Ef Core will make a single DB call, but it will cause a cartesian explosion.
For each product, there will be (Product.Colors.Count * Product.Styles.Count) rows returned.
So if one of the products has 5 different Colors and 3 different Styles, I will get 15 rows back from the DB for that single product (as well as all the rest).

If I change `AsSingleQuery()` to `.AsSplitQuery()` Ef Core will make 3 calls to the DB.
1 for the Products, 1 for the Colors, and 1 for the Styles. Which will result in much fewer rows returned to the expense of more DB calls.

My main question is this:

If restrict the amount of products I'm interested in by using FIrstOrDefault()/SingleOrDefault/Take(3)/etc, is there any point using a Split Query?

The following will return only 2 rows.

```
var productsSplit = _db.Products
    .Include(p => p.Colors)
    .Include(p => p.Styles)
    .AsSingleQuery()
    .Take(2)
    .ToList();
```

So that seems to solve the Cartesian Explosion problem.
But am I just passing that problem onto SQL.

I can see from the Output window that the above C# generates a far more complicated query.

Will this Single, more complicated query be much slower than the 3 smaller queries that will be used in the Split query? To the point that the Split Query is better?

Comment: The point is that entities you include may fetch the same row, at which point multiple queries may be more efficient. So if .Take(2) returns multiple colors/styles with the same Id but for different products,a split query may be more efficient. You can easily test this. I only look at split queries when fetching larger datasets, because the risk of returning a lot of the same sub entities is higher, so performance can be gained.

Comment: Will one be slower than the other? Possibly, but only you can tell that by doing your own measurements.

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). There is too much variables to say something concrete here, because this hugely depends on actual database, data and so on.

Comment: _"The following will return only 2 rows."_ - how did you check that? My understanding that this will return 2 _products_ but actual number of rows fetched from the database still will be depended on number of colors and styles for those products.

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight are the `Colors` and `Styles` correctly filled? Do you have any `Select`'s in the query?

Comment: Actually I think you're right @GuruStron.  I think it is still exploding.  It seems that Ef-Core is receiving a lot of duplication of data and then piecing it together when it gets it.  Maybe  the answer is use Split?

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight it should, otherwise how would it get all the needed data. Check where exactly "top 2" is placed.

Comment: @GuruStron Would I be correct in saying that it doesn't really matter unless there are a lot of Colors & Styles?

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight my opinion on the subject - yes.

Comment: And @GuruStron,  in your opinion if there is a lot, SplitQuery is the best???

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight in my opinion - you should measure =) Personally for the Take(n) (where n is relatively small and there are not much colors/styles per row) scenario I would start with single query and if there are problems with performance would investigate.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that the Cartesian explosion is not just around the # of rows, it is also the number of columns. In a case where a Product has Colour options and Style options to consider, it's not just the combination of AxBxC rows, but also colsA+colsB+colsC columns. So if Product has 20 columns, colour has 4 columns, and style has 12 columns where you have 100 products with an average of 5 colours and 5 styles per product,

- Single Query would return 100x5x5x(20+4+12) columns worth of data. (90,000 columns)
- Split query would return 100x20 + 100x5x4 + 100x5x12 columns worth of data. (10,000 columns)

This isn't quantitate in that a column could be something like an INT or TINYINT, or it could be a VARCHAR(MAX) when considering the entire volume of data coming over the wire into memory for EF to re-arrange back into related entities.

Before considering split queries vs. single queries, you should look at ensuring that the situation actually requires retrieving the entities back, or could be served by projecting a result object with the relevant data. For instance for searching it is not usually prudent to return back entire entity graphs for something like a search result. You might want something like a colour or style count, but it is typically far, far better to build a query that projects a summary of the entity aggregate for the results which can be paginated etc. Then when the user selects an item to drill down into details for, query the database for the complete graph for that single entity. There the Cartesian Explosion is still a factor, not so much for the AxBxC where "A"  = 1, but more-so for the colsA+colsB+colsC consideration. If colsB & colsC are relatively small tables in terms of column count and column size, and a reasonable # of rows, the Cartesian is more than manageable. If you see larger #s of rows or columns, or heavier columns in these tables then `AsSplitQuery` is an option to minimize that impact. As can further projection to exclude columns you don't need.